# Wordpress search relation from AND to OR

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce, relation

WordPress search function works with the "AND" way of showing search result instead of "OR". When I search for a product (WooCommerce) named "bear and the bunny" while using the query "bunny", no products are found. When I search for "bear" the book shows up. This shows the standard search function is VERY ineffective in my opinion.

I have been looking everywhere but cannot find a way to change the standard wordpress search query from the "AND" to "OR" relation. I did find a plugin, however these have their limits, they dont provide me with the basic option im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, its a plugin. It's outdated but does the job by providing contextual search results.

[Better Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search/)